# Тестирование LocalTime

Tags: java, junit, java-8

У меня есть метод который меняет свое поведение в зависимости от LocalTime.now() Как протестировать метод, в метод хочу подставлять разное время?

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(helloMessage());
    }

    public static String helloMessage (){
        LocalTime afternoon = LocalTime.of(12,00);
        LocalTime  now = LocalTime.now();
        if(now.isBefore(afternoon)){
            return "Good morning";
        }else return "Good day";
    }
}
```

Comment: все подобные вещи трестируются при помощи инъекции зависимости. добавьте [mcve] в вопрос и я (или не я) покажу как

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, спасибо

Comment: пожалуйста, перечитайте как сделать [mcve] и сделайте так как там описано

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я не совсем понял о минимализме, но для jvm этого было достаточно.

Comment: вот теперь все правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы сделать ваш вариант более трестируемым нужно улучшить дизайн:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter(LocalTime.now());
        System.out.println(greeter.helloMessage());
    }
}
```

**Greeter.java**

```
public class Greeter {
    private LocalTime now;

    public Greeter(LocalTime now) {
        this.now = now;
    }

    public String helloMessage() {
        LocalTime afternoon = LocalTime.of(12, 00);
        if (now.isBefore(afternoon)) {
            return "Good morning";
        } else {
            return "Good day";
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете легко протестировать класс **Greeter**:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class GreeterTest {

    @Test
    public void helloMessage_beforeAfternoon_returnsGoodMorning() throws Exception {
        Greeter cut = new Greeter(LocalTime.of(11, 0));

        assertThat(cut.helloMessage(), is("Good morning"));
    }

    @Test
    public void helloMessage_afterAfternoon_returnsGoodDay() throws Exception {
        Greeter cut = new Greeter(LocalTime.of(12, 1));

        assertThat(cut.helloMessage(), is("Good day"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Хороший наглядный пример, Спасибо. Для более чистого и полного теста думаю необхомо задавать значение по ближе к границам. Хочу указать время за одну минимальную долю времени к полудню, как остановить это время?

Comment: что значит остановить время? для чего вам это надо?

Comment: В классе LocalTime реализованы наносекунды, похожий функционал как в моем примере может использовать более точные значения, а бизнес логика метода может выполняться и больше секундны например или зависть от того же "железа". Хочу один раз написать тест и выполнять на чем угодно, Java она ведь такая.

Comment: никто не мешает вам в момент теста подсунуть любой экземпляр LocalTime с любым значением. если вы хотите можно сделать проверку хоть для каждой наносекунды, но в целом это не правильно.  юнит тест проверяет интерфейс, а не реализацию.

Comment: В таком случае все стало на свои места. Укажите Ваши импорты в тестах. Спасибо

Comment: добавил. хотя они совершенно стандартные.